# Send Akka messages with database update

Tags: scala, akka, slick

I am trying to implement a method in scala that performs couple of database updates using Slick (in the same DB transaction) and then sends several akka messages. Both sending messages and db updates should be atomic. In JEE world it happens pretty much transparently with JMS and DB(JPA for instance) participating in the same transaction and being coordinated by JTA. How do I achieve it with Akka and Slick. Examples would be very beneficial.

Comment: why don't you want to send messages after committing database transaction? Or do you need perform some database interaction as reaction on that messages in same transaction?

Comment: I need to be able to rollback DB transaction if I failed to send any of the Akka messages and return an error.

Comment: Akka doesn't provide any kind of message delivery guarantees out of the box. It can be done (with a reliable proxy for example), but maybe if you need this behavior you might be better suited to just stick to JaveEE.

Answer (score 0):

To continue the discussion in comments, As I see the solution to your problem:

Start with the main actor which performs db interaction. E.g. on message `Start` it updates database using Slick and saves `Connection` to actor's instance varibale and send messages to child actors. That actors have to send to your Main actor confirmation, for example message `ConfirmTratnsaction`. In the reaction on that message you perform commit on previously saved `Connection` and close it(or release it to the pool). Also, `Main` actor has to supervise that child actors. If that actor fail after sending message(or timeout occurs) you have to rollback transaction via saved `Connection`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Looks like very involved solution and if you have more than one place like this but with different actors/db we would be reinventing the wheel in multiple places. I was hoping for simpler solution.